# Bxslider freezes after scrolling down on the page in ios 7

Tags: bxslider

When scrolling down past the bxslider and then scroll back up the bxslider doesn't work anymore and causes freezing when trying to swipe or click to move the bxslider.

This happens on ios 7.1 on iPhone.

EDIT:

ISOLATED DEMO:
http://blastohosting.com/bxslider_bug/

To reproduce simply scroll up and then down, then start using the slider. It will work for 1 or 2 slides and then stop working.

Comment: Same error here, if you have any update please share,

Answer (score 4):

you can use bxslider property:

```
touchEnabled: true
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this, check the bxSlider options page:

http://bxslider.com/options

and set the preventDefaultSwipeY:true, that worked for me.

Comment: I would think it would be the other way around.

Answer (score -2):

FYI

There's another guy maintaining his own bxslider modified version and he got rid of that issue. I was facing the same issue. Now works like a charm.
Repo here: https://github.com/smohadjer/bxslider-4

Cheers